# Error in displaying custom Google Map in Polymer

Tags: google-maps, polymer, polymer-1.0

I displayed simple Google Map successfully :

```
<google-map
    latitude="30.283"
    longitude="57.083"
    zoom="12"
    language="fa"
    disable-default-ui
    >
```

But when I try to add `position` style, it doesn't apply it and zoom control disappears, I guess the problem is in the way I add `additional-map-options`, but I don't know how to fix it:

```
<google-map
    latitude="30.283"
    longitude="57.083"
    zoom="12"
    language="fa"
    disable-default-ui
    additional-map-options='{"zoomControl" : "true",
    "zoomControlOptions" : {"style" : "google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL", 
    "position" : "google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT"}
  }'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Huh... it turns out that `polymer` does not know what is `google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT`... but it knows about the int `9`...

```
<google-map latitude="30.283" longitude="57.083" zoom="12" language="fa" additional-map-options='{ "zoomControl" : "true", "zoomControlOptions": {
"style": "google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL", 
"position": 9
}}' disable-default-ui></google-map>
```

This is working, but I don't know why. somehow the number 9 works even `console.log(google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT)` gives me `12`...

Look at this demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/4gq1jv3y/1/